# Android Java - Make two containers side by side with percentage width

Tags: android-layout, android-percentrelativelayout

I have this scenario in an android page:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lbltvFirstContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="90" >

        <RelativeLayout         
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbltvFirstText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSecondText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvFirstText"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:textSize="19dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:flexDirection="row"
                app:justifyContent="flex_end"
                app:flexWrap="wrap"
                app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
                app:alignItems="flex_start"
                app:alignContent="flex_start"
                app:showDividerVertical="middle"
                app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider_flexbox">

                <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    android:id="@+id/btnButton"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                    app:icon="@drawable/btnButton"
                    app:iconTint="@null" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/first_icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/grey_24dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

            </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/elements_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lblThirdImage"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvThirdText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblThirdImage"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:flexWrap="wrap"
            app:alignItems="stretch"
            app:alignContent="stretch"
            app:showDividerVertical="middle"
            app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/lblFourImage"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/four_image"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvFourText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvFourImage"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="18dp"  />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/lbltvFiveImage"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start"
                        android:src="@drawable/five_image" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvFiveText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvFiveImage"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/lbltvSixImage"
                         android:layout_width="32dp"
                         android:layout_height="32dp"
                         android:visibility="visible"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                         android:layout_gravity="start"
                         android:src="@drawable/six_image" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSixText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvSixImage"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/lbltvSevenImage"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/seven_image"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="start" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSevenImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvSevenImage"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tvEightImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/eigth_image"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tvNineImage"
                        android:src="@drawable/nine_image"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:id="@+id/lblTenImage"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_width="42dp"
                        android:layout_height="42dp"
                        app:icon="@drawable/ten_image"
                        app:iconTint="@null" />

                </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lbltvSecondContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="10">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I am trying to have two containers side by side, `lbltvFirstContainer` and `lbltvSecondContainer`,  where I would set width by percentage so in the second container I can put just a ">" like a button to go to another page so after searching I found somewhere to use those `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="10"` but looks like that doesn't work.... do you have a direction to make those two main containers with percentage width? Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Edit:

after @Cheticamp 's suggest I changed as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".80"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/left_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/left_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbltvFirstText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:textSize="19dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Matricola:" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvSecondText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="4dp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvFirstText"
                        android:textColor="@color/area_frg"
                        android:textSize="19dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:flexDirection="row"
                        app:justifyContent="flex_end"
                        app:flexWrap="wrap"
                        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="50%"
                        app:alignItems="flex_start"
                        app:alignContent="flex_start"
                        app:showDividerVertical="middle"
                        app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider_flexbox">

                        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                            android:id="@+id/btnButton"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:layout_width="45dp"
                            android:layout_height="45dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                            app:icon="@drawable/btnButton"
                            app:iconTint="@null" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/first_icon"
                            android:src="@drawable/grey_24dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:layout_width="24dp"
                            android:layout_height="24dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.5"
                            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lblThirdImage"
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/wifi"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="start" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvThirdText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblThirdImage"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:flexWrap="wrap"
                    app:alignItems="stretch"
                    app:alignContent="stretch"
                    app:showDividerVertical="middle"
                    app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/lblFourImage"
                                android:layout_width="32dp"
                                android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/thermo"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="start" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFourText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblFourImage"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:textSize="18dp"  />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/lbltvFiveImage"
                                android:layout_width="32dp"
                                android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="start"
                                android:src="@drawable/full_batt" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFiveText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvFiveImage"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:textSize="18dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/lbltvSixImage"
                                 android:layout_width="32dp"
                                 android:layout_height="32dp"
                                 android:visibility="visible"
                                 android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                 android:layout_gravity="start"
                                 android:src="@drawable/power" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvSixText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvSixImage"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:textSize="18dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/lbltvSevenImage"
                                android:layout_width="32dp"
                                android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/gsm"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="start" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvSevenText"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lbltvSevenImage"
                                android:gravity="start"
                                android:textSize="18dp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/tvEightImage"
                                android:src="@drawable/eight_image"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/tvNineImage"
                                android:src="@drawable/nine_image"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:layout_width="24dp"
                                android:layout_height="24dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

                            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                                android:id="@+id/lblTenImage"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:layout_width="42dp"
                                android:layout_height="42dp"
                                app:icon="@drawable/play"
                                app:iconTint="@null" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>



        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".20"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/right_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/right_guideline"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

using those `ConstraintLayout` but seems it keeps returning this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mytestapp, PID: 32175
    java.lang.AssertionError: LEFT
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.Guideline.getAnchor(Guideline.java:147)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.solver.widgets.ConstraintWidget.immediateConnect(ConstraintWidget.java:1620)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.applyConstraintsFromLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1359)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:1253)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:1149)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25532)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25532)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1350)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1419)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1323)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25532)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25532)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6957)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25532)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.measureChildWithMargins(RecyclerView.java:9384)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1653)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:148)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:43)
        at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:2003)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:918)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:831)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22900)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3619)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3087)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2060)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8430)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:250)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:970)
```

so I re-checked what I typed in XML and seems it looks ok but maybe shall I have forgot or mistaken something ?

Thanks!
Cheers!

Edit 2 :

Hello @Cheticamp , following your suggest I started from scratch to create a ConstraintLayout with two guidelines dimensioned by percent as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/test_left_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/test_right_guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.20"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toEndOf="@id/test_left_guideline" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

so it's supposed to see in Design those two guidelines side by side since I put `app:layout_constraintLeft_toEndOf="@id/test_left_guideline"` so after I could put two RelativeLayouts as containers following those guidelines but it looks like both guidelines starts from the left side of the parent window... which attribute I should set to make those two guidelines side by side? Thanks in advance! Cheers

Comment: You would need to change the top-level _RelativeLayout_ to a _ConstraintLayout_ to use `app:layout_constraintWidth_default` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`. If you do, know that `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`  takes a number between 0.0 and 1.0. You would also need to apply constraints to the other views.

Comment: hello @Cheticamp , I changed with `ConstraintLayout` taking a look on `GuideLines` but looks like it returns an error as I reported in `Edit:` section of the main post.... maybe I missed something to consider? Thanks in advance! Cheers

Comment: I think that guideline's orientation needs to be vertical (it runs top to bottom). I suggest that you start with a very simple layout using ConstraintLayout that gets you started and you can get working and build upon that.

Comment: hello @Cheticamp , following your suggest, as you can see in main post at `Edit 2` section , I created a simple layout test but looks like they still keep staying both at most left side of the parent.... what I should have missed?..

Comment: Guidelines don't accept constraints. The percentage is always the distances from the left side of the ConstraintLayout and not relative to anything else.

Comment: Ah, what if I want a left container with 90% width of the parent and a right container with 10% width of the parent ?...

Comment: Set one guideline at 90%. Constrain the left (width="0dp") to the left of parent and the right to the guideline. For the right container, constrain the left to the guideline and right to parent (again width="0dp"). That will make two containers: one 90% of the width on the left or the layout and the other 10% of the width on the right of the container.

Comment: @Cheticamp , you mean just add only one guideline at 90% then add , for example, two relativelayout as containers based on that guideline added first?...  Or just two guidelines?

Comment: One guideline at 90%.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cheticamp , now it works all like charm! :-) How I can set your answer where you were explaining about guideline at 90% and constrain all stuffs as the solution because I don't see that flag side to the answer?....